# How to check resume capability of current URLSessionDownloadTask?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Currently i'm working on downloading a file from server, and this is working good.

---

my question is how would i know that url has resume **capability** or not before actual download started?

bellow is some code snippet,

```
class Downloader:NSObject,URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    /*
     SOME PROPERTIES & DECLARATIONS
     */

    override init() {
        super.init()
        let backgroundSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: url.absoluteString)
        backgroundSessionConfiguration.networkServiceType = .default
        self.defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundSessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    }

    func start(_ block:DownloaderCompletionHandler?) {
        guard self.input == nil else { return }
        guard self.output == nil else { return }
        if let data = self.resumableData {
            self.downloadTask = self.defaultSession.downloadTask(withResumeData: data)
        }else {
            let request = URLRequest(url: self.input!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 0.60)
            self.downloadTask = self.defaultSession.downloadTask(with: request)
        }
        self.downloadTask.resume()
    }
    func pause() {
        self.downloadTask.cancel { (data) in
            self.resumableData = data
        }
    }
}
```

please , guid me on this situation.
**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: What do you mean by resume capacity ? Are you referring to the capability to resume after the download has been interrupted ?

Comment: @user1046037, yes, i've edited that part of question. can you show some example?

Comment: All `URLSessionTask`s can be suspended and resumed. Simply call the function `suspend` / `resume`. Try it for yourself I haven't tried it myself. As far as I know it has nothing to a specific URL

Answer (score 0):

A download can be resumed only if the following conditions are met:

- The resource has not changed since you first requested it
- The task is an HTTP or HTTPS GET request
- The server provides either the ETag or Last-Modified header (or both) in its response
- The server supports byte-range requests
- The temporary file hasn’t been deleted by the system in response to disk space pressure

→ Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloadtask/1411634-cancel

Answer (score -1):

if you send a request with Range in HttpHeaders and receive a 206 status code in response , then you can resume the download. otherwise download can not be resumed.

read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests)

Comment: hi, thanks for instant response, will try and give you results.

Comment: yes i got status code 206, but my question is to get this info while downloading is on going. is there any way for this.?